# Are mongoose embedded document objects mongoose objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have the following code snippets which have an embedded comment within an item

```
var CommentModel = new Schema({
  text: {type: String, required: true},
}, {strict: true})

CommentModel.options.toJSON = { transform: function(doc, ret, options){
  delete ret.__v;
  delete ret._id;
}}

Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentModel);

var ItemModel = new Schema({
  name:        {type: String, required: true},
  comments:    [ Comment ]
}, {strict: true})

Item = mongoose.model('Item', ItemModel);

Item.findOne({}, function (err, item) {
  item.comments.forEach(function(o) {
    console.log(o.toJSON)
  })
})
```

However it doesn't appear that the resulting array of objects which are returned are mongoose objects or at least that the transformation doesn't get applied. Am i missing something somewhere or is this just not supported in mongoose?

Comment: I thought the `toJSON` option was set on the schema, not the model.

Comment: That's probably my dodgy naming conventions. It's set on the schema.

Comment: Oh yeah, duh, I should have looked closer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a couple problems:

`ItemModel` should reference the schema `CommentModel`, not the model `Comment` in its schema:

```
var ItemModel = new Schema({
  name:        {type: String, required: true},
  comments:    [ CommentModel ]   // <= Here
}, {strict: true})
```

You need to call `toJSON` in your `console.log`, not pass the function as a parameter:

```
Item.findOne({}, function (err, item) {
  item.comments.forEach(function(o) {
    console.log(o.toJSON())   // <= Here
  })
})
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense (and now suitably renamed my objects). However I still get "TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'toJSON'"

Comment: @Nick Hmm...I did run this code and confirmed it worked.  This is with Mongoose 3.5.1.

Comment: Aha yep my mistake - i have my models and schemas in seperate files which i wasn't exporting so yep that fix works great. Thanks!

Comment: I was referencing the model and getting estrange errors, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could define a schema method like this:

```
CommentModel.methods.toJson = { ... };
```

Later edit:
I am referring to a method, not the options. You could also filter certain data within this method, as a bonus :)

Comment: Not entirely correct. toObject and toJSON have options which can be specified in this way. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject